# MySQL selecting distinct names from two columns

Tags: mysql

I have two columns of coaches names:

```
coach1
JOHN
JACOB
MARY

coach2
JOHN
JACOB
HENRY
```

I would like to select all DISTINCT values between the two columns.

So that my SELECT statement will read,

```
JOHN
JACOB
MARY
HENRY
```

with no duplicates. Any suggestions as to the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT COACH1 AS NAME FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT COACH2 AS NAME FROM TABLE
```

Is a way to do. I'm not saying it's the "most" efficient to do, though :) Shouldn't be too bad. `UNION` by default will select only distinct values.

Comment: I've seen that :) I'm trying hard to type fast :P